# How to catch the datePicker close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the date picker and it is working fine. Few of my web page need some calculation using the start and end date. 
I would like to be able to do the calculation when the datepicker close.

I am using:

> < input class="datePicker" id="endDate" name="endDate" type="text" value="04/10/2013 23:00" />

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `onClose` method.

Refer to API Documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose)

Comment: Any advice on how to do this in pure JS?

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Just add your function into `onClose` event. Sample code is below.

```
.datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function () {
        alert('Datepicker Closed');
    }
});
```

Comment: not working in my side.